# Error in if (REML) p else 0L : argument is of length zero

Tags: r, lme4

I am trying to build a model for my result. Exact same model works for bigger data set where my current data set (Alder3) is a part of. But now I just copied the results into a new excel sheet and suddenly I received the following error. I tried even with one random effect and still I got the same error. Any help is appreciated.

```
M1<- lmer(Blood_sugar~ Age +(1| Animal)+(1| Parents), data = Alder3,subset(Alder3,Fresh_Frozen==0, Inc==0))
```

Error in if (REML) p else 0L : argument is of length zero

Answer (score 0):

this part of the code `subset(Alder3,Fresh_Frozen==0, Inc==0)` is used for the REML argument of `lmer`, which only takes a single logical value of i.e.(`TRUE` or `FALSE`). 
Try `M1<- lmer(Blood_sugar~ Age +(1| Animal)+(1| Parents), data = Alder3,subset = Fresh_Frozen==0 & Inc==0)`